# preg_match Vs preg_match_all browser error not php?

Tags: preg-match-all

Hi all i have the following:

```
$str = base64_encode(preg_replace("#\s|\r|\t|\n#", " ", file_get_contents("../www.cms.actwebdesigns.co.uk2/logged.php")));
if(preg_replace("#(PD9waHAg)((?!(Pz4g)).)*#is", $str, ))
{
    #print_r($matches);
    echo "<xmp>".base64_decode($matches[0]."Pz4g")."</xmp>";
}
```

now this works but i want to be able to use it for all occurrences on page. (finds php segments in page) So i used preg_match_all but returns a browser error (page has been moved or no longer exists) Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

This is a real longshot, but I seem to recall some versions of Internet Explorer having a "feature" where so-called *friendly error messages* were be displayed for pages where:

- an error status code (e.g. `404 Not Found`) was returned, and
- the actual HTML response was smaller than a certain number of bytes.

If your code was sending an error response already, and the change to `preg_match_all()` ended up shortening the output enough, it may have triggered the friendly error message.

If you're not using IE, or if your script is returning a non-error status code, then I have no idea what could be causing this.

Comment: well poo... lovely reply.. still going no where tho! thanks anyway.

Comment: its not a browser error, its a connection error, which means theres something going wrong while connected to the server. Shouldn't be a problem with regex ... i don't know any case where regex caused a problem with server connection. Do you work with socks-con? have you changed back to preg_match? what happened then?